# Grep only gids from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, grep

I want to `grep` only group IDs from `/etc/passwd`. Now I only came up how to grep the names, with:

```
grep -oE '^[^:]+' /etc/passwd
```

which gives me:

```
[frynio@manjaro ~]$ grep -oE '^[^:]+' /etc/passwd
root
nobody
dbus
bin
daemon
mail
ftp
http
systemd-journal-remote
systemd-coredump
uuidd
dnsmasq
rpc
usbmux
avahi
colord
cups
deluge
git
lightdm
nm-openconnect
nm-openvpn
ntp
polkitd
frynio
```

How can I change this regex, to omit the first three `:`s and then start matching with `[^:]+`? (cuz the `^` before it matches the beginning of the line, that's why I can extract the names, and I want something to match the position after 3 colons).

PS I **have** to use `grep`

Comment: `cut` or `awk` with a suitable delimiter would be simpler imho

Comment: Have to use grep

Comment: Why do you have to use grep? It's not the best way to do it.

Comment: You can do it if your grep provides a PCRE mode e.g. `grep -Po '^([^:]*:){3}\K[^:]*'`

Comment: It may be you have to use `grep` for your assignment. But do you have to use `/etc/passwd` or would `/etc/group` suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GNU grep (which is the default on linux), you can do it with the `-P` option, and a lookahead assertion:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=(?::[^:]*){3}$)' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that this is *impossible* to do with standard `grep` as `grep` will always return a full line matching the given pattern.  It would be possible with GNU `grep`, but it would but non-portable to many other types of Unices, difficult to maintain (or to modify to do more interesting stuff), and non-trivial to understand.

Easier with `awk`:

```
getent passwd | awk -F ':' '{ print $4 }'
```

This get the `passwd` data and extracts the fourth `:`-delimited field.

Or, even easier with `cut`:

```
getent passwd | cut -d ':' -f 4
```

although with `awk` you'd be able to do more interesting processing, such as only getting the GID for UIDs less than 1000:

```
getent passwd | awk -F ':' '$3 < 1000 { print $4 }'
```

One could also choose to parse out the third `:`-delimited column from the output of `getent group`, which would have the additional benefit of not giving you duplicates.

```
getent group | cut -d ':' -f 3
```

Comment: Dude, I am supposed to use `grep`. Forgot to mention

Comment: @Frynio `getent passwd | cut -d ':' -f 4 | grep .`

Answer (score 1):

Is it permissible to use two `grep` processes? If yes, try:

```
grep -oE '^([^:]+:){3}[^:]+' /etc/passwd | grep -oE '[^:]+$'
```

Comment: You could replace ``{3,3}``  with ``{3}``.

Comment: @G-Man, Yes, you're right. Thanks for mention!

Answer (score 0):

Is it permissible to use `pcregrep` instead of regular `grep`? 
If so, you can do

```
pcregrep -o2 '^([^:]+:){3}([^:]+)' /etc/passwd
```

`pcregrep` extends the functionality of the `-o` option
to let it match a grouped substring. 
In the regular expression in the above command,
`[^:]+:` matches a `passwd` file field,
so `^([^:]+:){3}` matches the first three fields
(username, password field, and UID). 
The following `([^:]+)`, which is the second group in the regex,
matches the fourth field, which is GID. 
The `-o2` flag tells `pcregrep` to output only that second group.